# gcc compilation error /usr/bin/ld: cannot find

Tags: c, gcc, debian, ld

I wrote a simple program in C:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

And when I try to compile it (gcc test.c) i have the following error :

```bash
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: type [0x13] unknown in the ".relr.dyn" section
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 ignored because incompatible when searching for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: type [0x13] unknown in the ".relr.dyn" section
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 ignored because incompatible when searching for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/usr/bin/ld: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: type [0x13] unknown in the ".relr.dyn" section
/usr/bin/ld: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ignored because incompatible when searching for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/usr/bin/ld: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: unknown type [0x13] in the ".relr.dyn" section
/usr/bin/ld: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ignored because incompatible when searching for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm on debian 11.

I hope somebody will help me.

thanks

Comment: Please show us the exact command-line that you use to build.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's gcc test.c

Comment: It seems as if you have multiple compiler/linker systems installed, and somehow mix them up. Does that trigger some memory? A simple "gcc test.c" on a vanilla Debian will never produce such an error.

Comment: @thebusybee how can i resolve this ?

Comment: The simplest way is to wipe the system and start from scratch. But this is only the [ultima ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(U)#ultima_ratio). We need a _lot more_ of information if you want us to repair your system. Think about what you need to know if a stranger comes and tells you such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by upgrading the `gcc-10` package from 10.3 to 10.4.